# How to switch sprite side left and right without changing local scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, scale, game-development

I'm making a 2D game and I want my player when he is moving left and right based on the **Input Key** to switch the side of my player's sprite.

The way I'm handling it so far which it works for now is by changing the local scale on the X-Axis like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

The default is for the player to face the right side but when he press the A button the player will look to the left side and when he press D it will look back to the right side.

So far everything is good, but when I try to increase my player's size when he collects a power up everything is messed up.

To increase the size I'm using the DOTween package which provides an easy way for scaling up an object like this:

```
transform.DOScale(new Vector3(2, 2, 2),1.5f);
```

After that I realise that messing with the scale it can become really messed up.
My question is there any better way to handle the sprite side switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is an easy solution.

I suppose that you are using a [Sprite Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html) component for your player.
On this component there is an option `Flip` which is used to flip your sprite on 2 Axis (X,Y). You can use the X-Axis in order to flip your spite left and right.

Simple create a reference of your `Sprite Renderer` component in your above script and then use the `flip` property to change your sprite side.

Here is an example:

```
private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

void Start()
{
    spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
    }
}
```

Now you can use your [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/) to scale your player.

Comment: That's awesome. Actually works perfect, I just copy and paste your code and it fits very well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
Vector3 localScale;
private boolIsFacingRight = true;
void Update()
{
    localScale = transform.localScale;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        localScale.x *= isFacingRight ? 1 : -1;
        isFacingRight = true;
        transform.localScale = localScale;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        localScale.x *= isFacingRight ? -1 : 1;
        isFacingRight = false;
        transform.localScale = localScale;
    }
}
```

That way you are only flipping your character on a single axis and you maintain the scaling versus setting it to a new vector 3 every time.